# How to use ImageRect images into movieclip in corona sdk?

Tags: coronasdk

In my game i have to use movie clip. it runs perfect in iphone.when i use 4x images.it will not working properly.how to use imagerect image into movieclip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used newest movieclip.lua file.my problem solved.